# C puzzle — pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Basically what I'm trying to achieve here is having global variable with array of pointers to struct which size isn't known at compile time — in my example below it's `my_struct **tab`. In the final version I want to call a JNI method which will initialize my array of pointers and I want to keep them for some other methods usage.

Unfortunately I'm not a C programmer and I really struggle with this problem. Below I show what I tried to do; obviously, it's not working. Any constructive feedback would be really helpful.

(Sorry for missunderstanding with includes it's supposed to be a C code )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int tag;
} my_struct;

my_struct **tab;

void * get_pointer_to_struct() {

    my_struct * s;
    /* allocate memory */
    if ((s = (my_struct *) malloc(sizeof (my_struct))) == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return s;
}

void free_structures(int j) {
    for (int a; a < j; a++) {
        my_struct *s;
        s = (my_struct *) tab[a];

        /* free memory */
        free(s);
        tab[a] = NULL;
    }
}

void init_pointers_array(int j) {
    my_struct * temp_arr[j];
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        temp_arr[i] = (my_struct *) get_pointer_to_struct();
        temp_arr[i]->tag = i;
    }
    tab = temp_arr;
}

int main() {
    //initialization
    init_pointers_array(10);
    //usage
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
        if (tab[a]) {
            my_struct * str_tmp = tab[a];
            printf("Integer that you have entered is %d\n", str_tmp->tag);
        }
    }
    //free mem
    free_structures(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any code that starts with `#include <cstdlib>` and `using namespace std;` is clearly not C code; that is C++ material.  Either those first two lines are bogus and should be deleted (and the question retagged and re-edited back to C) or it is really C++ and you need to be sure you know which language you're working in.

Comment: This is C, not C++.  `using namespace std;` does not a C++ program make.

Comment: ahhh, i'm sorry i didn't point this out earlier, the target code will be C not C++, this is just skeleton code showing the way of thinking. Target Code will be part of C library porting JNI calls.

Comment: When you say the size of the struct is not known at compile time, do you mean ultimately the size beyond your current `tag` field will be variant throughout the array, or just variant for *that* array (in other words, all items in *that* array will be the same size) ?

Comment: size of array of pointers to structs is unknown at compile time, it will be collected from env variable when specific jni function will be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_struct * temp_arr[j];
```

then

```
tab = temp_arr;
```

is **wrong.** (Not only the placement of the `*` qualifier is horrible and there are superfluous casts that severely decrease code readibility, but) `temp_array` is a **local auto array,** so it will be deallocated when the function returns. Doing anything with its address afterwards results in undefined behavior. You may want to `malloc()`ate some memory for the struct instead (the casts are only there in order the code to be usable in C++. In C, it's strongly discouraged to make redundant typecasts):

```
my_struct **tab;

tab = (my_struct **)malloc(sizeof(tab[0]) * number_of_structs);

int i;
for (i = 0; i < number_of_structs; i++) {
    tab[i] = (my_struct *)malloc(sizeof(tab[0][0]));
}
```

And for freeing it:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < number_of_structs; i++) {
    free(tab[i]);
}

free(tab);
```

Comment: The question was originally tagged C, but the code was clearly C++.  The casts on `malloc()` are needed in C++, of course.  You should update your answer appropriately.

Comment: the problem here is that i have to use my specific function returning pointer to allocated structure (imitated by void * get_pointer_to_structure in my example)

Comment: @kookee I don't see any problem with that.

Answer (score 3):

This code is so unreadable I'm surprised anyone bothered to read it. Follow these guidelines and all your problems will be solved:

- Use std::vector (or similar array class) instead of raw arrays
- Don't use dynamic allocation if you don't need it, but if you do use **new** instead of malloc
- Whenever you use dynamic allocation, do so within a class that owns the object and follows the RAII principle
- Don't use global variables

Comment: thank you for your comment. I skimmed the code, and I did not realize that it is C++. I thought it is C. I remove my post.

Answer (score 0):

Several points:

- `get_pointer_to_struct` can simply return the result of `malloc`. And change it's signature to avoid the extra casts to `my_struct*`.
- `temp_array` is created on the stack, so it no longer exists when `init_pointers_array` exits. `malloc` it as well.  This is your BIGGEST problem.
- This is in general. You do alot of superfluous work, which bloats your code something terrible. Try to avoid redundant casts and unneeded variables.